# Spring Boot Dev Tools: Crash on hot reload with CommandLineRunners and Spring Data Repositories

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm developing a project with Spring Boot 1.3.2, Spring Data MongoDB and Spring Security, using Dev Tools, with IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3, using Maven.

I did read the Spring Boot Developer Tools [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools), and carefully configured everything as indicated, and the hot reload worked just fine.

Then, since i needed to perform some tasks during the application startup, mainly connecting to the database and perform validations, and insertions if needed, i decided to use `CommandLineRunner` beans like this:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseInitializer {

   @Bean
   CommandLineRunner verifyConfiguration(ConfigurationRepository repository) {
       return args -> { 
           // The id is a provided one and i can't modify it.
           if (repository.findOne(...) == null) { // this is the offending line 
               //perform some tasks here  
           }
       };
   }

   // more CommandLineRunners following the same approach

}
```

If i restart the application, everything works just fine, no crashes, no errors, but when i trigger the dev tools hot reload, then it fails, and throws this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.adrisasws.gestor.CesteriaApariciApplication.main(CesteriaApariciApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.adrisasws.gestor.configuracion.api.outputs.ConfiguracionFacturacion using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments 
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:64) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:251) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1186) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1134) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:870) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:283) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:271) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:271) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:191) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2224) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1855) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1672) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findById(MongoTemplate.java:614) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findOne(SimpleMongoRepository.java:119) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.findOne(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.adrisasws.gestor.Inicializacion.lambda$inicializacionConfiguracion$1(Inicializacion.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.adrisasws.gestor.configuracion.api.outputs.ConfiguracionFacturacion]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:101) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

I'm aware that it complains of `ConfiguracionFacturacion` being an interface, one of the properties of the document is declared as an interface, but in my code, i always instantiate a concrete implementation, as i said, everything works fine on a normal startup, and during execution.

So basically my questions are:

- why does it work normally but fails on hot reload?, is it a bug and then i should submit an issue?
- or it is a really bad practice to use abstractions in the entity classes annotated with `@Document` and i should consider refactoring?

P.S. if you need more information, ask for it, and i'll update the question.

**Update**: The first time the `CommandLineRunner` runs, when the element in the database is not present, so the  `findOne()` call returns null, the Hot Reload, does not fail.

**Update2**: Avoiding the `findOne()`, and using `exists()` and `count()` instead whenever possible, solves the problem, but doesn't seem like a definitive solution, since, fortunately, in my use case I don't really need to access the data, just check if it is present, or to know how many records there are, but in some other use cases, where data access is mandatory, developers can't enjoy the benefits of the hot reload from DevTools.

If it is of any help, here's more information that about this particular issue:

In the specific case of Spring Data MongoDB, when a field in the `@Document` class is declared as an interface, then in the database, in the embedded document representing that field, a property named `_class`, with the value of the fully qualified class name of the concrete implementation is inserted, for example:

```
public class AddressDocument implements Address {
    ...
}

@Document
public class PersonDocument {
    private Address address;
    ...
}
```

when performing the following operation:

```
PersonDocument p = new PersonDocument();
p.setAddress(new AddressDocument(...));
repository.save(p);
```

then the mongo document stored in the database would have the following form:

```
{
    ...
    address : {
        "_class" : "package.AddressDocument",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So it is really obvious to think that Spring Data is using `_class` to determine what class to use in order to be able to instantiate the class, and for some reason, DevTools is bypassing that mechanism.

Comment: Setting aside whether or not it's a bad practice, if your use of an interface in your entity classes works normally and only fails during a reload then that's something that we (the Spring Boot team) would like to look at and fix if we can. Can you please open a Spring Boot issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new) with a small sample project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: created the [demo project](https://github.com/saljuama/devtols-hotreload-crash-demo) and the [ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5098) in the issue tracker. Also i'm updating the question with a small detail i've found while creating the demo project.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson if you post an answer of your findings you've posted in the [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5098) i'll gladly accept it.